# Storybook Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I add Storybook to my project and some of stories throw errors.

Unexpected error while loading ./components/Modals/InviteUserModal/inviteUserModal.stories.tsx: Cannot access '**WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT**' before initialization
ReferenceError: Cannot access '**WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT**' before initialization

this is my story for this component.

```
import { ComponentProps } from 'react';
import InviteUserModal from './InviteUserModal';

export default {
  title: 'modals/InviteUserModal',
  component: InviteUserModal,
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<ComponentProps<typeof InviteUserModal>> = (args) => (
  <InviteUserModal {...args} />
);

export const Modal = Template.bind({});
Modal.args = {
  isOpen: true,
};
```

I have this issues on stories when i use types from global interfaces.